# How to Write Persian TexT in TexMaker

Tags: xetex, texmaker, persian

I am trying to write Persian text in TexMaker on Fedora. I have installed xepersian, but this basic example fails to build and run.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
این فقط یک آزمایش است
\end{document}
```

The error is:

> (fontspec) You must change your typesetting engine to,
>   (fontspec) e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
>   (fontspec) "latex" or "pdflatex".

Following the hint, I have tried Options->Configure TexMaker and then selecting XeLatex + View PDF under Quick Build Command, but still it fails. 
Also, I fail to build this file with xelatex from the command line, where I get similar errors and more.

Here's the full output:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.3) 16 FEB 2020 07:09
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**fa.tex
(./fa.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/xepersian.sty
Package: xepersian 2019/05/01 v22.7 Persian typesetting in XeLaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-07-25 L3 programming layer (loader)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2019-07-25 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count80
\l_tmpa_int=\count81
\l_tmpb_int=\count82
\g_tmpa_int=\count83
\g_tmpb_int=\count84
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count85
\c__ior_term_ior=\count86
\c_log_iow=\count87
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count88
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count89
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count90
\l__iow_indent_int=\count91
\c_zero_dim=\dimen102
\c_max_dim=\dimen103
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen105
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen107
\c_zero_skip=\skip41
\c_max_skip=\skip42
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip43
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip44
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count92
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count93
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen108
\g__intarray_font_int=\count94
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count95
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count96
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count97
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count98
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count99
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count103
\c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count104
\g__fp_array_int=\count105
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count106
\l__sort_length_int=\count107
\l__sort_min_int=\count108
\l__sort_top_int=\count109
\l__sort_max_int=\count110
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count111
\l__sort_block_int=\count112
\l__sort_begin_int=\count113
\l__sort_end_int=\count114
\l__sort_A_int=\count115
\l__sort_B_int=\count116
\l__sort_C_int=\count117
\l__str_internal_int=\count118
\c__str_replacement_char_int=\count119
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count120
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count121
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count122
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count123
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count124
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count125
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count126
\l__regex_balance_int=\count127
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count128
\l__regex_mode_int=\count129
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count130
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count131
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count132
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count133
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count134
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count135
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count136
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count138
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count139
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count140
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count141
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count152
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count155
\l__regex_step_int=\count156
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count157
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count158
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count159
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count160
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count161
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count162
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count163
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count164
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen130
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen133
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count165
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count166
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 v L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count167
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count168
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count169
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count170
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count171
)
Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec) LuaTeX.
(fontspec)
(fontspec) You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec) e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec) "latex" or "pdflatex".
Type <return> to continue.
...
l.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort.
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
10051 strings out of 494562
200563 string characters out of 6177417
216248 words of memory out of 5000000
13780 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
54i,0n,67p,288b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: don't use `minimal` class for documents, use `article` or another "real" class. You need to use xelatex, but if you get an error with that show the error that you get. You also need to make sure that you have the font that you specify.

Comment: The article class does not work either. Should XB always precede the font name?

Comment: `XB`  isn't part of the syntax it is that you are using a font called `XB Niloofar` that is its name, like  `Times Roman`. But the error you show shows that you are using pdflatex, you need to use xelatex.  see the very first line `This is pdfTeX, `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really easy to make this work. Thanks to the hint given by David in the comments, the default build from the toolbar was using pdflatex.
First, select XeLaTex from the drop-down menu.
Also, import enumerate before the xepersian package. Then press the Run button from the toolbar and it would build successfully. You can view the PDF output on the right by selecting View from the toolbar. Last but not least, make sure you have the specified font installed on your system.

[image]